# How add ".indexOn" in my security rules of firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i have this warning in my front end

[image]

My data in firebase is this:

[image]

after basic i have a key, i try with this rule:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true,
 "workers": {
    "report":{
   "basic":{
      "$groupid":{
        ".indexOn": "date"
     }}
   }
  }
 }
}
```

but the warning persist!

how can config the rules in firebase?

Comment: Please copy the text of error messages and code directly into the question so they're easier to read and search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think that the `$groupid` is not required, because the error message does not have it:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "workers" {
      "report" {
        "basic" {
          ".indexOn": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... and consider adding further security rules; these permissions are alike `777` on a web-server.

Comment: Correct on both counts. Indexes in your Firebase rules are defined on the place where you execute the query. Since you run a query on `/workers/report/basic`, that's where you define the index.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it proofs, that these warning message are understandable... at least while taking them literal and not trying to interpret something into them, which is not there.

Comment: Thanks ! This work for me and I will add more rules